# Accessing active page's name during ionViewCanEnter

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

In Ionic 2, I'm trying to determine the name of the sending page (PUSHER) before entering the pushed page (PUSHEE).

In the PUSHEE, I have an `ionViewCanEnter` where I would like to determine the PUSHER's name. When I use the NavController to get the active page though, it returns `undefined`. The NavController itself isn't undefined, just the response from `getActive`. Any recommendation for getting the name of the page PUSHER?

```
ionViewCanEnter(): boolean {
    console.log('active page', this.navCtrl.getActive());
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, there is not a good way for getting the name of the active page. However, from the PUSHER, you can send a string parameter:

```
this.navCtrl.push(HomePage, {pusherName: "MyPageName"});
```

And in PUSHEE:

```
ionViewCanEnter(): boolean {
    console.log('active page', this.navParams.get(pusherName));
    return true;
}
```

**Edit:**
Notice that you can get the name of a class (and hence the page name) using this:

```
(this).constructor.toString()
```

In my experiment, however, the name of the constructor gets optimized out when you run `ionic` with `--prod`. So any other way that you try, make sure to test it with `--prod`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to access the previous page via `getViews`

```
ionViewCanEnter(): boolean {
    console.log('getViews', this.navCtrl.getViews());
    var all_views = this.navCtrl.getViews();
    var last_view = all_views[all_views.length-1];
    var last_view_name = last_view.name;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

A simple example to redirect to another page:

```
<button ion-button  (click)="redirectHomepage();">Home Page</button>

import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { HomePage } from '../home/home';
@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-level',
  templateUrl: 'level.html',
})
export class LevelPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
  }

redirectHomepage()
{
 this.navCtrl.push(HomePage);
 }


}
```